# setOnItemClickListener not working with Custom TextView ListView Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `TextView` `ListView` that contains a selection of `fonts`. When the user presses on one of these fonts, a function is called that changes the `Typeface` of some other `TextView`.

```
final ListView fontsListView = (ListView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.MenuLayout);
final String[] fonts = new String[] {
        "Aclonica",
        "Arimo-Regular",
        "Calligraffitti-Regular",
        "CherryCreamSoda",
        "Chewy",
        "ComingSoon",
        "Cousine-Regular",
        "CraftyGirls",
        "CreepsterCaps-Regular",
        "Crushed",
        "FontdinerSwanky",
        "HomemadeApple",
        "IrishGrover",
        "Nokora-Regular",
        "JustAnotherHand",
        "Kranky",
        "LuckiestGuy",
        "MaidenOrange",
        "Montez-Regular",
        "MountainsofChristmas-Regular"
};
ArrayList<String> fontsList = new ArrayList<String>();
fontsList.addAll( Arrays.asList(fonts) );
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new AdapterFontViewHolder(getActivity(), fonts);
fontsListView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Aclonica();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
fontsListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Why doesn't this work? It doesn't seem to detect the click at all.

Here is my custom Adapter:

```
public class AdapterFontViewHolder extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;
    private Typeface[] fonts;

    public AdapterFontViewHolder(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.fonts_simple_row, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        // Create Typeface only once and use it.. Path you can change as per your directory
        fonts = new Typeface[]{
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Aclonica.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Arimo-Regular.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Calligraffitti-Regular.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/CherryCreamSoda.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Chewy.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/ComingSoon.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Cousine-Regular.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/CraftyGirls.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/CreepsterCaps-Regular.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Crushed.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/FontdinerSwanky.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/HomemadeApple.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/IrishGrover.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Nokora-Regular.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/JustAnotherHand.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Kranky.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/LuckiestGuy.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/MaidenOrange.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Montez-Regular.ttf"),
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/MountainsofChristmas-Regular.ttf"),
        };
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder vHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // Create Instnce of view if its null & store object in ViewHolder (a class)
            vHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fonts_simple_row, parent, false);
            vHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);

            //Set ViewHolder instance in convertview in a tag as a object
            convertView.setTag(vHolder);
        } else {
            // reuse as already converview is instansiated & it holds ViewHolder instance in tag
            vHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        vHolder.textView.setText(values[position]);

        //Here From Fonts array take Typeface
        vHolder.textView.setTypeface(fonts[position]);

//        vHolder.textView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) fonts[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Should I set the ClickListener in my custom adapter instead? If so, how would I go about doing that?

**Updated Answer:**

```
fontsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                    long arg3)
            {
                LaunchFont(fonts[position]);
            }
        });
```

This is the function that is called and depending on the position in the ListView, sets up a different Typeface:

```
public void LaunchFont(String fonts) {
    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fonts + ".ttf");
    text_View.setTypeface(myTypeface);
    view.findViewById(R.id.edtextDesigner).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    view.findViewById(R.id.toggleText).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    view.findViewById(R.id.closeFontMenu).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.findViewById(R.id.MenuLayout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

This way I don't have to have a unique function for each Typeface.

Comment: did you got any error message in logcat?

Comment: @sasikumar No error message whatsoever. The app kept running. It seems like the click listener just isn't connected for some reason.

Comment: you say  `setOnItemClickListener` in your question but you have implemented `setOnItemSelectedListener` ?

Comment: do listview.setOnItemClickListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after the following line:

```
final ListView fontsListView = (ListView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.MenuLayout);
```

Add below code:

```
fontsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
            long arg3) 
      {
            String value = fonts[position] ;
            // assuming string and if you want to get the value on click of list item
            // do what you intend to do on click of listview row
      }
   });
```

Comment: This was the most efficient solution. See my updated answer above.

Answer (score 1):

setOnItemClickListener instead of setOnItemSelectedListener

```
fontsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Aclonica();
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
fontsListView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
```

to

```
fontsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
```